# MSBuild appending MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE to the end of my URL

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild

I am trying to configure a build in TFS to deploy to our test box for continuous integration.  The problem I'm having is that TFS wants to append the `MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE` to the end of my URL which is causing the deploy to return a socket error:

```
 Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.   Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath).
```

Here are my MSBuild Arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=[ip address]:8172/MsDeploy.axd 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent 
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
```

The server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit server with IIS 7.5.  We have no problems using the publish feature of Visual Studio 2010 to deploy to the test box using the Url above.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days an tons of searching, I discovered the issue.

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=[ip address]/MsDeploy.axd 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
/p:DeployIisAppPath=[name of website in iis]
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
```

As it turns out, the publish method was the culprit.  RemoteAgent cannot interpret the deploy correctly, which is why it fails to serialize.  WMSVC is the appropriate setting for the publish method.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify `MsDeploy.axd` in your `MsDeployServiceUrl`. Also, I see you don't have a `DeployIisAppPath` value set. You should set it to the name of your website in IIS.

Below is an example from one of our CI builds.

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=http://[YOUR WEBSERVER URL]
/p:DeployIisAppPath="NAME-OF-WEBSITE-IN-IIS"
```

Comment: I tried it that way to no avail.  I'm wondering now if it has something to do with how we set up users.  I'll run some tests on the server to see if there's an issue there with the firewall.